# set the user mass data of dynamic body in and engine

Tags: android, andengine

How to set the user mass data of dynamic body in andEngine. My problem is that in my game when i increase the speed of running player, the player on jump cover very long distance with x-axis. This distance changes with the speed. Any solution please..

Comment: Please post the jump code. Maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: runnerPhysicsHandler.setLinearVelocity(runnerPhysicsHandler.getLinearVelocity().x,-8);

Comment: can you please give me example of using impulse.. i am new to AndEngine

Comment: See method called applyLinearImpulse. It basically gives the body a "kick". The physics extension in AndEngine is based on Box2D, the manual (http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) contains useful information about physics in the engine.

Comment: impulse did not solve it. can you please tell me how to set the usermassdata(); of dynamic body. what type of argument pass to it..

Comment: A quick look in the Manual provided me with this example: fixture->SetDensity(5.0f);

body->ResetMassData();
Please read he manual and learn how the engine works.